# Drilling into timber frame wall from loft

Tags: wiring, drywall, attic, new-home, timber-framing

I live in a 2021 new build house in the UK. Detached, timber frame, stud walls. I have a sloping roof on two sides, on the other two sides they are just vertical walls (in the shape of a triangle at the top if that makes sense).

I'd like to get a cable into the upstairs wall from the loft. At the edge of the loft there are these recessed bits as shown below, which are timber and are past where I imagine the ceiling of the upstairs roof ends. I've tried drilling vertically down in one position and was still drilling into wood after about 10-15cm. I tried in another position at an angle that goes towards the inside of the loft, and drilled through a few cm of wood then there was a gap now I've hit something else which feels like more wood.

I can't get cable rods into either hole.

Am I barking up the wrong tree completely? Should I not be drilling here or have I just missed the top of the wall somehow?

[image: wall]

Comment: It's hard to tell what we are looking at in that picture. Is the camera right-side-up, and looking at the back side of drywall? What is that plywood above you? Is it subfloor for the floor above you? Or is it a wall and the camera is pointing straight down/up?

Comment: @TylerH ah yes I see what you mean. I can take a better pic in the morning if needed, but the blue rods are pointing vertically, the chipboard at the back of the picture is vertical at the edge of the house.

Comment: @TylerH this is in the loft btw, above the wall I want to get into.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that to be more than a couple of '2x4' laid flat, but sometimes you do see bigger beams around the top, edge beams and the like. 

How will you access the hole from inside the room?

Comment: @handyman straight down below where I'm drilling (if I'm drilling in the right place!!) is an ethernet socket and a power socket on the wall already. The wires for those don't go up to the loft but down. But behind those sockets there's a couple inch gap then some insulation. The plan is to poke a cable rod down the hole that I make and it hopefully comes out behind the existing socket, I can run the cables using that and it's sorted. I just don't seem to be able to get into the wall cavity!

Comment: What we here in the States call "lumber" is often called "timber" in the UK & Europe. Can you confirm whether you mean your house is "[timber framed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timber_framing)" or do you mean that the house was "stick built" using dimensional lumber/timbers. When I saw "timber frame", I presumed it was as per the link, and that 15cm (~3") was a very reasonable distance to go, possibly further. Heck, even here the US, the top plate of a stick-built  wall would be 3" thick.

Comment: Heck @FreeMan, it gets even more complicated than that even! Whilst yes, timber framed in the true UK sense does mean the old Tudor etc. style buildings. But nowadays most people understand timber framed to mean a timber frame (studs/framing etc.) on the inside with a brick outer leaf (veneer in the US?). There are very few true timber framed homes in the UK (whereas, I'm in Norway and here they are nearly all timber, 2x6 frame, sheathing/cladding on the outside and drywall on the inside!).

Comment: @GoldieLocks, well I don't suppose you can hurt anything by drilling deeper. If you didn't go through at 15cm, then it's likely the beam (for want of a better word) is going to be 20cm or even 22.5cm deep...

Comment: @handyman sounds like Norway builds mostly like the US. It doesn't help that I've been watching an _oooold_ series of _This Old House_ and they're rebuilding an actual timber frame barn (8x8" posts & beams), so that's been on my mind. Drilling through one of those timbers would require a smidge more than going 15cm!

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. I drilled further and got through it, it was just massive! All I needed was the confidence I wasn't going to mess up something structural :) and yes, I won't pretend to know the difference between the various timber framing methods but yes, in the UK I understand it to mean a brick/cladded breezeblock outer shell then a stud plasterboard wall on the inside!

Comment: Good news @GoldieLocks. And me and FreeMan are far enough away should your house fall down, we'll be okay ;-)